# cts:search pass the node dynamically

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

Is there a way to have the below code working?

```
let $node := 'childnode'
return
cts:search(/root/$node, 
    cts:and-query((
        cts:collection-query('collection')
        
    ))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to dynamically build and execute the XPath for the `cts:search` `$expression` parameter is to generate the search expression as a string and then use [`xdmp:value()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:value) to parse and execute:

```
let $node := 'childnode'  
let $expression:= "/doc/" || $node
let $query as cts:query := cts:and-query((
        cts:collection-query('collection')
    ))
return xdmp:value("cts:search("||$expression||"," ||$query||")")
```

Comment: Thanks, but does this impact the performance of the query?

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be much of a difference. Try it out and see.